# Dispatch and get elements to render reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, dispatch

I have an array with 2 elements to render `ItemComponent`

In `ListComponent` i dispatch to call api and get 2 difference image to set varible `image` in store

```
const ListComponent = (array) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  return array.map((item,index) => {
    dispatch(
      //dispatch call api, set value image in store
      getImage(item...)
    )
    return <ItemComponent />
  })
}

const ItemComponent = () => {
   const {image} = useSelector(...)
   return (
     <img src={image}} />
   )
}
```

---

```
//Reducer
let inintitalState = {
  image: "",
};
   
export function Image(state = inintitalState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "GET_IMAGE":
  
      return { ...state, image: action.data };
    default:
      return { ...state };
  }
}
```

---

```
//Action
export function getImage(item...) {
return async(dispatch)=> {
  try{
    const res = axios("GET", URL(item...))
    dispatch({type:"GET_IMAGE", res})
}
catch(error){
 console.log(error)
}
}}
```

The result is tag `img` in `ItemComponent` will show the same image, i want it to render difference image

dispatch need to use in ListComponent because it need parameters

pls guide me

Comment: Please share initIal state and reducer code.

Comment: i've updated reducer and action code

Comment: In the redux store, you want to store two images and then you want to show these two images in ItemComponent using two <img/> tags. Am I right?

Comment: that right, i have try store with array but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

It should work:

```
let inintitalState = {
  image: [],
};
   
export function Image(state = inintitalState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "GET_IMAGE":
  
      return { ...state, image: [...state.image, action.data] };
    default:
      return { ...state };
  }
}
```

Now the image will be an array and it should be map

```
   const {image} = useSelector(...)
```

Comment: yes `image` is able to map but the `ListComponent` already map 2 time, so `ItemComponent` will loop 4 time and the tag `img`  result will be  the same image.
Do it have any chance to useSelector in `ListComponent`  and transmission to `ItemComponent` , I know dispatch is async and it will cost infinity render when state change

Comment: Could you share what data your array variable contains that you map and dispatch getImage(). Is your item is a api URL?